# Exo Player not playing video from url

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-storage, exoplayer

Am trying to integrate ExoPlayer for the first time. I tried Following some tutorials two to be exact, but the video wouldn't even play. So I went to the documentation and still it doesn't play. When I checked the Logs found this exception

```
E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0x80001001, actionCode 0, while in state 6
E/MediaCodecAudioRenderer: Audio codec error
  java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_dequeueOutputBuffer(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2698)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.dequeueOutputBufferIndex(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:106)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.drainOutputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1819)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:792)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:989)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:490)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error
  com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: MediaCodecAudioRenderer error, index=1, format=Format(2, null, null, audio/mp4a-latm, mp4a.40.0, 96000, en, [-1, -1, -1.0], [1, 44100]), format_supported=YES
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:566)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
 Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecDecoderException: Decoder failed: OMX.google.aac.decoder
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.createDecoderException(MediaCodecRenderer.java:945)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:813)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:989)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:490)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65) 
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_dequeueOutputBuffer(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2698)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.dequeueOutputBufferIndex(SynchronousMediaCodecAdapter.java:106)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.drainOutputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1819)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:792)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:989) 
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:490) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Here is the code from the PlayerActivity

```
playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    btnFullscreen = findViewById(R.id.btn_fullscreen);

    //Fullscreen activity
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    //Get intent Extras
    String urlExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra("videoUrl");

    //Parse video url
    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(urlExtra);

    ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();

    // Bind the player to the view.
    playerView.setPlayer(player);

    // Build the media item.
    MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri);
    // Set the media item to be played.
    player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
    // Prepare the player.
    player.prepare();
    // Start the playback.
    player.play();
```

Comment: also add code for a better understanding

Comment: @MDEV I have made the edit

Comment: Are you seeing this error on an emulator or on a physical device?

Comment: @Mick on a physical device

Comment: ExoPlayer does not like something about that video, specifically something about the audio. Have you tried other videos, perhaps from other sources? Have you tried downloading the video that is giving you trouble and playing it locally to see if you get different results? And, are other Android apps capable of playing the video?

Comment: I tried to download it onto my pc it played I also tried uploading other videos they failed to play. Let me try the other suggestions you have given @CommonsWare

Comment: FWIW, by "download", I meant download in the app (e.g., using OkHttp) and playing that file in the app.