# Video Playing But Audio Isn't On VideoView

Tags: java, android

This is a question that has been asked multiple times but I tried multiple answers but no luck, I tried the exo player first and it wouldn't even stream and the question is unanswered ([Exo Player not playing video from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74397043/exo-player-not-playing-video-from-url)) So I went through a longer process of building a custom controller for a videoView but it won't play audio.

Before upload to firebase I compress the video like so

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String videoPath = null;
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(strings[1]);
            videoPath = SiliCompressor.with(UploadActivity.this)
                    .compressVideo(uri, strings[2]);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return videoPath;
    }
```

Then I save the download links and upload.
Then I retrieve and play the video like so

```
//Get intent Extras
    String urlExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra("videoUrl");

    //Parse video url
    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(urlExtra);

    //Set up Video to play
    videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
    videoView.start();

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            seekBar.setMax(videoView.getDuration());
            videoView.start();

            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE,
                    AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        }
    });
```